# dynamically buttons need to add inside div container angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

currently i am working on dynamic form creation (Angular) by clicking add button div will be created this i have done.

I want to add two buttons delete and save. I am not getting how to add.

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-form?file=src/app/app.module.ts) link

Comment: please let me know what needds to be add don't close the ticket

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-form-rjxaml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts ? (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @eko thanks almost correct but here i have one more query how to add method to that function

Comment: Something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-form-rjxaml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts ?

Comment: hi @eko you can post as a answer i can upvote almost we are complete i will do the CSS change 

are you available in telegram can you please share other way to contact

Comment: contacting via comments is fine :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232392/discussion-between-mr-m-and-eko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leveraging the built-in `index` for the `ngFor` would be helpful to keep track of the dynamically created divs inside the `ngFor`

```html
    <div id="content">
      <div
        class="contentInside"
        *ngFor="let container of containers; let i = index"
      >
        I'm number {{ i }}
        <button (click)="saveMe(index)">Save</button>
        <button (click)="deleteMe(index)">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-form-rjxaml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)